# CSS Tile flip animation assistance

Tags: jquery, css, html, css-animations

So i am attempting to follow a tutorial ( http://davidwalsh.name/css-flip ) about creating a tile and being able to flip it over and have other content on the other side. I've attempted doing this but i cannot seem to figure it out. I posted a link below to what i have so far. If anyone could help me out i would really appreciate it. Thanks

http://fiddle.jshell.net/s5CCc/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `ontouchstart` with `hover`, because touch events are only handled on mobile devices, and hover phases will work on both, and I'm assuming you're testing this on your computer.

So to fix, add content to the `front` and `back` comments, as seen in the fiddle **below,** and change `ontouchstart` to `hover`.

[Here is the fixed fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/s5CCc/3/)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, after fixing what you suggested, it still doesn't seem to work. [here's](http://fiddle.jshell.net/s5CCc/4/) what i came up with.

Comment: @user2466564 No, it works, see put your mouse out of the result box, then put it back in, and it will flip.

Comment: Sweet, i was using it in chrome before and it seems to work in firefox. Any idea how i can make it compatible with chrome?

Comment: @user2466564 Yes, use `-webkit-transform` and for more browsers, `-ms-transform`: http://fiddle.jshell.net/s5CCc/5/

Comment: I did what you suggested, but its a bit screwed up in chrome but still works in firefox. http://fiddle.jshell.net/s5CCc/7/

Comment: @user2466564 Add webkit a bunch more, in the `perspective`, `transform-style`, `transition`, etc, see [this fiddle.](http://fiddle.jshell.net/s5CCc/8/)

Comment: @user2466564 Your welcome, and it won't hurt to upvote.  You know, since you *have 15 REP* ;)